# Random files (invalid encoding) appearing in home directory

Tags: nautilus, filesystem

There are various files with random names

This is a recent issue, but I'm not sure how it's happened.
The only new install on my system was `remmina` and I've been playing around a lot with screenlets and other display settings (ccsm).

They are all of 0 bytes, and reappear with different names after I delete them. `ls` shows them as `??` in listings. However nautilus shows the following :

[image: Nautilus Screenshot showing the random files]

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with the Classic Desktop.

**Update**: Kernel Log:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/629269/. My hard *is* failing as per SMART tests.

Comment: It sounds like disk failure, could you post the contents your `/var/log/kern.log` file on http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the link to your question?

Comment: image backup your PC before your hard-disk fails - suggest use clonezilla.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo: please remove the update and use that to create an answer, then upvote your answer! It will get you some rep and others will see that there's an answer when looking at the question! The way it is now it will get kicked once every while and end up in the active list of unanwsered questions ;)

Comment: I would immediately backup the files to an external drive and buy a new disk, an answer can always be added.

Comment: Its under a continuous backup sytem since a long time.

Comment: Is it definite that the failing hard-disk is causing the issue? It has not repeated itself so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was due to my failing hard disk. However I'm not sure about this and would post an update if and when this happens again.