# Delete corrupted folder

Tags: filesystem

I am trying to delete a folder in my home directory; its name is completely garbled.  In Nautilus, the garbled text is followed by 'Invalid Directory.'

Deleting it with Nautilus stalls; I can't type in the garbled name in the terminal.

```
peter@io_vbox:~$ ls -lbdR *
...
drwxrwxr-x 3 peter peter      4096 Jul 28 15:19 \346>\3152\357+\332)\363*\356,\253-\277+H&\266\033z\v\373\366\340\340?\314\022\274P\262\003\260鵿\303p\326\342\351\214\374f\016X\036r)!.\026
...
```

Any ideas?

Running 12.04; if it's of any importance, this is running in VirtualBox on a Macbook Air.  It was installed through VirtualBox.  I don't have any other signs of SSD failure that I've picked up on -- referring to this question: [Random files (invalid encoding) appearing in home directory](https://askubuntu.com/q/49483/42720)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "this is emulated in VirtualBox" - do you have a clone of your machine or another virtual machine and those files also appear there?

Comment: @Peter, Please can you post the output from ls -ldR * while in your home dir and post the line with the directory in question?

Comment: @Sergey, Thanks for the feedback; it's not a clone.  This only concerns one installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a file / dir has special characters and won't delete, you can try to remove it using it's inode number [more information on inodes in ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure).

To do so,

1. open a terminal window.
2. Change directory `cd` to the location of the files or directories with the "special characters".
3. Run

   ```
   ls -lbdRi *
   1312883 drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 Aug 31 11:49 special-character`
   ```

   Note the "inode" number (Here **1312883**)
4. Then run a find and remove on that "inode"

   ```
    find . -inum 1312883 -exec rm -rf {} \;
    find: ``./special-character': No such file or directory
   ```
5. and then to make sure that is has gone.

   ```
    ls -lbdRi *
    ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory
   ```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Awesome!  It worked.  How did you manage to replicate my problem, to solve it?  Thanks